How to convert a Tableau FIXED LOD to Power BI DAX?
{Fixed [For_Init], [For_Year], [Prod_Seg] : SUM({Fixed [For_Init], [For_Year],[Prod_Seg]: MIN (IFNULL ([UW Forecast]*[UW Factor], 0))})}

I have tried it the following expression :
Var a = CALCULATE(
        MIN(TableName[UW Forecast] * TableName[UW Factor]),
ALLEXCEPT(TableName, TableName[For_Init], TableName[For_Year], TableName[Prod_Seg])),
Return if(ISBLANK(a),0,a)

However it is not working as expected, can you help me the correct way of doing it please?


Can you provide input and expected output ?

I added the screenshot of Tableau and DAX Input and Output.
However it is not working as expected, can you help me the correct way of doing it please? enter image description here

Can you share your initial data ?

Is there any way you can convert the Tableau Expression to DAX. I just need the equivalent expression in DAX

I don't recommend converting from a language to another.

That's why I am asking for your input and expected output to replicate your need in DAX
